# Heap and stack in C Programming

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Currently I am studying C Programming in memory management.

- What memory abstractions does C provide ?
- What exactly is the    distinction between stack and heap?
- How do I use pointers to access    memory locations ?
- How do I allocate and free memory on the heap ?

Comment: Those are big topics and cannot be answered in a few words ：）

Comment: If this is all about C, why does it have a C++ tag? Memory management between the two varies vastly.

Comment: It's amazing what you find if you take any one of those bullet points and enter it in the search box on either StackOverflow or Google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: for these topics are too big to answer, you may search each one and learn it respectively from books or googles :) and this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap?rq=1) may help for your 2nd qeustion.

Answer (score 2):

To be EXTREMELY brief:

- Variables in a stack are lost when a function returns.  Variables in
  a heap can be accessed by any function, and the values are not lost
  until they are freed.  So, stacks are useful because they are simply "local" to a single environment (function).  Heaps are good when we need to access more "global" types of data, between functions.
- int * p = 4.  this means that you have created a pointer to memory address 4.
- *p is called "dereferencing the pointer p", which basically goes to the address stored in p .  you can do something like *p = 100, which means storing the value 100 at the address stored in p.
- to allocate memory in c, use malloc(...), where documentation can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/
- to free memory, use free(...), documentation found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/

Comment: I'd suggest you don't do people's homework for them or answer questions so blatantly in violation of the FAQ